# Check to see if div is present with jquery

Tags: jquery

```
if(.is-open close-now){
jQuery(".extra_div").click(function($){
            alert('"Sorry, this takeaway only accepts orders during its opening hours"');
        });
}
```

I think something like the above is what I need but I don't know how the if statement part should work out.

I'm looking to check if a certain div is present and then if it is, run the following jQuery on click code.

**Update 1**

```
if ($(.is-open close-now).length){
jQuery(".extra_div").click(function($){
            alert('"Sorry, this takeaway only accepts orders during its opening hours"');
        });
}
```

The two divs are

is-open open-now - open
.is-open close-now - closed

Comment: IS the div always present and possibly hidden? Or if the hours are outside business hours, the div doesn't exist on the page?

Comment: Presence check in DOM: if($(_selector_div_).length){

Comment: Sorry, picked this job up after but from what I can tell if it's closed and has the above div, then the other one isn't present at all

Answer (score 0):

You can easily check its `length`. If a certain element doesn't exist then checking its `length` returns false

```js
if($('.is-open').length){
  // exists
  console.log('is-open exists');
  // do stuff
}
if($('.not-is-open').length){
  // doesn't exist
  console.log('not-is-open exists');
  // do stuff
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="is-open">
</div>
```

Comment: Roughly what i'm going for but I updated post with the 2 divs, would it essentially be this but I swap in my ones